# loading JsonBuilder from external jar in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have written a groovy class that uses `JsonBuilder`. It works in eclipse, but when I try to run it outside of eclipse it complains and spits this *Unable to resolve class JsonBuilder* error. I googled this error and somewhere mentioned that groovy doesn't have `JsonBuilder` in it directly and I have to get it through a different jar. I downloaded groovy-all.jar and unzipped it under the same project dir, it works, but I was wondering how can I use it without unzipping it?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Just like in java:

```
groovy -classpath groovy-all-1.8.6.jar Generator.groovy
```